# Display data in desired form ,using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to get this output

```
Province 
 1.city 1 33poits
 2.city 2 33poits
 3.city 3 33poits
```

and what my current output is

```
Province 
 1.city 1 33points
Province 
 2.city 2 33points
Province 
 3.city 3 33points
```

please help just a newbie here, below is my php code

```php
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ccty WHERE ID=".$ID;
$results = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
    ?>  
    <table>  
        <tr><?= $row->PID; ?>
            <td><?= $row->SPID; ?><?= $row->points; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
    }
} else {
    echo "No record available!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one, your table-structure is invalid.

To only print the `PID` once per group, store the previous PID in a variable and check against it - only print it if its different from before.

You should also be using a prepared statement instead of a direct query.

```php
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT PID, SPID, points FROM ccty WHERE ID=? ORDER BY PID";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $ID);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($PID, $SPID, $points);
if ($stmt->num_rows) {
    echo '<table>';

    $previousPID = null;
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        if ($PID != $previousPID) {
            echo '<tr><td>'.$PID.'</td></tr>';
            $previousPID = $PID;
        }
        ?>  
        <tr>
            <td><?= $SPID." ".$points; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
    }
    echo '</table>';
} else {
   echo "No records available!";
}
```

Comment: @Dhruv - When editing a question, you shouldn't change the actual code. You can fix the formatting so it's more clear (adding spaces and line breaks), but changing things like: `<?=$foo ?>` to `<?php echo $foo ?>` isn't ok...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thank next time sure i will improve my personality.

Comment: @Dhruv - ...not changing the code is enough. I'm sure your personality is fine :-)